# How to execute ssrs report programmatically using c# WITHOUT open the browser

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reporting

i made a program using winforms that reproduce the execution of Reports.
meaning, i input dates: from.... to.... and the code Rerun the reports.

i used:

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Url.ToString());

and it works well, but it opens the IE,
now i want to run the url behind the scenes without displaying it in browser.
i tried:

> try
>                           {

```
                        WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url.ToString());
                        myRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            var statusResponse = response.StatusDescription;
                            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                            StreamReader readerr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                            string responseFromServer = readerr.ReadToEnd();
                            var responseServer = responseFromServer;
                        }
                        response.Close();
                    }
```

it just doesnt work!
what did i do wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK,
i found the problem.
a had an error:
"{"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."}
i just did not display it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reccomended approach for triggering report renderings via code is the via the SOAP api - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx